# Payload Array Nested Bug

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express

if im creating a product with 2 or less images it is working fine but if i add 3 images or more i don't know it doesn't work look in the request payload, every image is supposed to come in different element but instead i don't know why there is a nested array in it, can you help?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wcgs.png)

this is my backend code

```
const createProduct =  async (req,res,next) => {
    // try {
        let images = []
        console.log('1')
        if(typeof req.body.images === "string"){
            images.push(req.body.images)
        } else {
            images = req.body.images
        }

        const imagesLink = []
        console.log('2')

        // try {
            for(let i=0; i <images.length; i++){
                const results = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(
                images[i], {
                folder:"products"
                });
                 console.log('3')
    
                imagesLink.push({
                public_id:results.public_id,
                url:results.secure_url
                }
                )}  
        // } catch (error) {
            // console.log('ok')
        // }
        
        console.log('4')

        req.body.images = imagesLink;
        req.body.user = req.user.id
        const product = await Product.create(req.body);
        res.status(200).json({
            sucess:"true",
            product
        })

}
```

//this is my frontend code

```
const createProduct = ({history}) => {

    const [Product, setproduct] = useState('')
    const [Price, setPrice] = useState()
    const [productDesc, setproductDesc] = useState('')
    const [category, setcategory] = useState('')
    const [Stock, setStock] = useState('')
    const [images, setimages] = useState([])
    const [imagesPreview, setimagesPreview] = useState([])

    const { error, loading, success} = useSelector((state)=>state.createProduct)
    const alert = useAlert()
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const categories = [
        "Electronics",
        "Footwear",
        "Bottom",
        "Top",
        "Attire",
        "Camera",
        "SmartPhones" ,
        "Other"
    ];

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(error){
            alert.error(error)
            dispatch({
                type:CLEAR_ERRORS
            })
        }
        if(success){
            alert.success("Product Created Successfully")
            // history.push('/admin/dashboard')
            dispatch({
                type:NEW_PRODUCT_RESET
            })
        }
    },[dispatch, alert, error, history, success])

    const createSubmitHandler = (e)=>{

        e.preventDefault()

        const myForm = new FormData()

        myForm.set("name",Product)
        myForm.set("description",productDesc)
        myForm.set("price",Price)
        myForm.set("category",category)
        myForm.set("Stock",Stock)

        images.forEach((image)=>{
            myForm.append("images",image)
        })
        dispatch(AddNewProduct(myForm))
    }

    const createProductImagesChange = (e)=>{

        const files = Array.from(e.target.files)
        
        setimages([])
        setimagesPreview([])

        files.forEach((file)=>{        
            const reader = new FileReader()              
                reader.onload = ()=>{
                    if(reader.readyState===2){
                        setimagesPreview((old)=>[...old, reader.result])
                        setimages((old)=>[...old, reader.result])
                    }
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file)
            });
    };

  return (
<Fragment>
    <div className='sidebar-container'>
        <Sidebar/>
    <div className='create-product-container'  >
        <Typography style={{fontSize:"2.4vmax" , color:"tomato", margin:"2vmax" }} > CREATE PRODUCT </Typography>
        <form onSubmit={createSubmitHandler}>
            <div className='create-container' >
            <Spellcheck  className='create-svg' />
            <input type="text"
            placeholder='Product Name'
            value={Product}
            onChange={(e)=>setproduct(e.target.value)}
            required
            />

            </div>
            <div className='create-container' >
            <AttachMoney  className='create-svg'/>
            <input 
            placeholder='Price'
            type='number'
            readOnly={false}
            inputMode='numeric'
            defaultValue={null}
            required
            value={Price}
            onChange={(e)=>setPrice(e.target.value)}
            />
            </div>

            <div className='create-container' >
            <Description className='create-svg-2' />
            <textarea
            style={{resize:"none", border:"none", outline:"none"}}
            type="text" 
            cols="30"
            rows="5"
            contentEditable={false}
            onChange={(e)=>setproductDesc(e.target.value)}
            placeholder='Product Description'
            value={productDesc}
            required
            ></textarea>
            </div>

            <div className='create-container' >
            <AccountTree  className='create-svg' />
            <select onChange={(E)=> setcategory(E.target.value)} required >
                <option >Choose Category</option>
                {categories.map((cate,index)=>{

                   return  <option value={cate} > {cate} </option>
                })}
            </select>
                </div>

                <div className='create-container' >
                    <Storage   className='create-svg' />
                <input 
                required
                type="text"
                placeholder='Stock'
                name='Stock'
                value={Stock}
                onChange={(E)=> setStock(E.target.value)}
                />
                </div>
                <div className='create-container' >
                <input 
                required
                type="file"
                accept='image/*'
                name='avatar'
                multiple
                onChange={createProductImagesChange}
                />
                </div>
                <div className='image-mapping' >
                {imagesPreview.map((image,index)=>{
                   return <img key={index} src={image} alt='image' />
                })}
                </div>
                <Button className='create-product-btn'
                type='submit'
                disabled ={ loading ? true : false}
                >
                    Create
                </Button>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
  </Fragment>
  )
}
```

Im getting this error

The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Array

and i dont know why array is nesting within inside, if i am using only two images it works fine,